# Bevel issue: Beveling an object with both large and small elements

Tags: modeling, bevel

I'm trying to bevel an object. This object has mainly large surfaces, but also a few details. See image below. How should I go about bevelling this object?

Can I somehow exclude the details from being bevelled? Or should these details not be part of the main object to begin with?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! You could use the *Limit Method* option and a vertex group on the bevel modifier.

Comment: Never worked with Vertex Groups before, seen it in action in some video's though, so I get what you're talking about. I'll give this a go! Thanks!